# Yo Frankie game not working

Tags: 14.04, games

I have installed Yo Frankie game on 14.04 LTS. When I open the game it shows some clouds moving on the screen. No menu appears. What should I do?

Comment: Researching....

Comment: Have you installed Blender 2.49a or newer?

Comment: yes. I have blender 2.69

Comment: Any crashes or error messages?

Comment: I can confirm the same results whilst following the directions to use blender-player in the readme. I got the same results with the addition of a small black square in the middle that disappeared upon any mouse movement.

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to get it to work following the directions in the README so what I did was navigated to where I extracted the files, opened the yofrankie-win32 folder right-clicked on the highlighted file and chose Open With A Wine Application.

[image: yofrankie]

Some light research indicates that the inability to use the directions in the README may be a blender bug. This part I have not confirmed. However the instructions outlined above do work.

Comment: I am talking about the linux version of yo frankie.

Comment: Fixing blender is beyond me. file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the Ubuntu package.  The download from the website works (if you run the binary, not using "blenderplayer") -- see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yofrankie/+bug/899954